# Registry of different types of data

Tags: c++, types, stl, containers

I want to keep some kind of container where a type maps to one value of the type. So essentially what I want is a `std::map<std::typeindex, T>` where T depends on the type I index it with. `std::map` doesn't look like a nice way of doing this because the types are rigid. What is the simplest solution I can use for doing this?

Comment: Is there a fixed set of types for `T`?

Comment: You could map to `boost::any` maybe?

Comment: @DanielFrey: Yes. But I don't want to repeat stuff. Declaring that type `A` belongs to `T` is essentially a repetition of declaring the type `A` itself in my opinion.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Wouldn't that make it possible to store a `B` value that type `A` maps to? I want to enforce that type `X` maps to a value of type `X`.

Comment: @user2852456: Enforce it through a public interface: `template <typename T> T & Registry::get()` etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you map to a type-erased container like `boost::any`, you can at least recover the type if you know what it is:

```
std::map<std::typeindex, boost::any> m;

m[typeid(Foo)] = Foo(1, true, 'x');

Foo & x = boost::any_cast<Foo&>(m[typeid(Foo)]);
```

Comment: What advantages does this have over something like `void*`?

Comment: @user2852456: Try writing it with `void*` and compare!

Comment: @user2852456: OK, this may be hard to appreciate, but you can see by inspection that the solution I present doesn't have UB, whereas the one you're about to write will be far more brittle.

Comment: Does boost::any store it as a value, instead of keeping a reference to it? If so, how does it manage to do that for any type?

Comment: @user2852456: UB is undefined behaviour, as you would get from casting a pointer to the wrong type and dereferencing it. `boost::any` uses type erasure, done by storying a dynamically allocated object privately. There's an internal base class that has a virtual `typeid`-type function which is used to check that the `any_cast` is valid.

Comment: So `boost::any` dynamically allocates it but handles memory management itself as opposed to using `void*`. What's the difference to using `std::shared_ptr<void>`?

Comment: @user2852456: `boost::any` owns the object. `shared_ptr<void>` implements race-free, shared ownership semantics on top of that, which is much more (but it also costs more).

Comment: Oh wait, I should have perhaps compared it to `unique_ptr<void>`. What's the difference compared to that?

Comment: @user2852456: Type safety.

Comment: @user2852456: And the fact that `unique_ptr<void>` doesn't make sense, since unlike `shared_ptr`, unique_ptr` does *not* contain a type-erased deleter.

Comment: So if I want the container to own the objects, I should probably use `boost::any`?

Comment: @user2852456: That's why I suggested it. But you can use Daniel's idea, too; I just think it's less safe and more expensive with no benefit; or you can write it yourself with `void*` and then think about how that would work, which would be educational.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `shared_ptr<void>`:

```
std::map<std::typeindex, std::shared_ptr<void>> m;
m[typeid(T)] = std::make_shared<T>(...);
auto pT = std::static_pointer_cast<T>(m[typeid(T)]); // pT is std::shared_ptr<T>
```

Or course you would add some wrapper to ensure that the two `T`s per line match and you don't accidentially access an empty `shared_ptr<void>`.

Comment: This solution looks syntactically nice (and +1 for that), but one should note that you're paying the price of type erasure as well here, but you're also paying for shared, race-free ownership semantics although this may not be what's desired, and the static cast requires discipline to produce well-defined behaviour. The `boost::any_cast` by contrast never causes UB.

Comment: @KerrekSB Given that the OP is a bit vague about the requirements, I think it's OK that we all offer some options and OP can analyse and picks what's best for him. (and therefore +1 for your answer as well)